# How to call superclass variable in a subclass method java

Tags: java, abstract-class, superclass

I have an abstract class called User, and a subclass called Staff that extends User. The User class contains a method: protected abstract void setId(String newId){} :which sets a private variable 'id' in the User class. So my problem is  when I go to create the setId() method in the Staff class, how do I refer to the 'id' in the User class if it is private? As far as I'm aware the 'id' variable cannot be set as protected. Thanks to anyone who can help!

```
@Override
public void setId(String newId){
    if(checkValidId(newId)){
       ????
    }
}
```

Comment: `super.setId(newId)`, assuming that's what the super method does. If the field is private you cannot access it otherwise.

Comment: if `User` means human, and `Staff` means a stick or staff, then you probably want "has-a" which generally means composition and not inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create setId method inside User class and access it through Staff class.

```
public abstract class User{

...
   public void setId(String id){
      this.id=id;
   }

}

public class Staff extends User{

...


   public void setStaffId(String newId){
       if(checkValidId(newId)){
          setId(newId);
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a getter method within the superclass called getID() which simply returns 'this.id'. The method can be called from any class which extends the abstract class and can be used to gain the value from within the id field. If that is what you are aiming for :)

Its important to note that you can do this because whenever you will construct a new object for Staff, the very first line within the constructor must make a call to the constructor within User in order to set the required field. E.g. the id field in this case.

Below is a working example which dynamically sets the ID starting from the value 5. You can run it to confirm the results or take a look at the screenshot attached below.

```
abstract class User{
    static int count = 5; 
    private int id; 

    public User(){
        this.id = count++; 
    }

    public int getID(){
        return this.id; 
    }
}

class Staff extends User{
    public Staff(){
        super();
    }
    public int getID(User x){
        return super.getID(); 
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Staff x = new Staff(); 
        System.out.println(x.getID()); 
    }
}
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lodGW.png)